# Are classes that are not sets big?

Tags: set-theory

A simple textbook reference would probably suffice here; I’m just not sure where to look, as I haven’t done much set theory.

Let $C$ be a class that is not a set. Is it true/provable/whatever that for any set $S$, there is an injection from $S$ to $C$? (I’m not even totally sure what the right way to phrase the question is, but hopefully the intuitive idea is clear.)

Comment: @Eric: I was looking for that. I *knew* that I had answered something similar before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean by "class" (or rather *proper* class). Assuming some nice enough version of set theory+classes (e.g. [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)+[Global Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice)), then the image of a set under a function is a set ([Axiom of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#Set_axioms)). It can then be proven that for every set $A$ and every proper class $C$ there exists an injective function $f\colon A\to C$. This is the usual argument of taking a maximal subset $A'$ of $A$ which injects into $C$ and using the fact that the image of $A'$ cannot be all of $C$ (as it is not a set)